# Error CS1056: Unexpected character '$' Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I had a Xamarin Project on Visual Studio 2015, for some reason I moved it over to latest version of Xamarin Studio (based on MonoDevelop), and I'm getting this error:

`Error CS1056: Unexpected character '$' (CS1056)`

Here's where it's happening:

```
...
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Title}";
        }
```

I'm using the new feature of C# 6.0 called "String Interpolation". **My code worked fine on Visual Studio 2015**, why am I getting this error??

Comment: what xamarian compiler are you using?

Comment: @DanielA.White What do you mean?? I'm trying to build an Android app.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: @DanielA.White, Xamarin Android 6

Comment: Works fine for me, using Mono 4.2.2 (explicit/7b87787)

Comment: I just ran into a similar issue with `?.` and `nameof`. With the same Xamarin Studio, v5.10.2, I copied a class from one compiling Profile78 PCL project to another Profile78 PCL project. As soon as I did, these C# 6 errors started showing up.

Comment: @patridge I couldn't find a fix for this so just changed all the code that was using C# 6 to older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a setting inside the project properties that are controlling the ability to use C# 6 features.

Double-click every project involved to open the Project Options, go to Build > General [> C# (for PCL projects]. From there, choose Version 6 under C# Language Version.

### Example for platform projects

[image: Picking a C# language version for platform projects.]

### Example for PCL projects (note the tab switch needed)

[image: Picking a C# language version for PCL projects.]

Comment: Didn't work for me. It'll raise another error. Did you try it yourself?

Comment: Yes. It worked for all my C# 6 errors once I set it on all the projects involved in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can lie in a bug in some editors that mixes Unicode with ascii. This makes everything look correct in visual studio but when opened in another editor it can be seen that the file is corrupted.

Answer (score -3):

The current version of Xamarin Studio does not support C#6.0 features, including String Interpolation.

There is a preview release of Xamarin Studio that uses the Microsoft Roslyn compiler and does support string interpolation (do note however that as of January 11th 2016 the current release will not actually BUILD code that uses C#6 features).

You can get the preview release [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/53121/preview-release-xamarin-studio-6-0-with-roslyn-support/p1).

Comment: Your statement is incorrect, I am using XS 5.10.2 with Mono 4.2.2 and C# 6 features are supported. The 'Rosyln' refactoring, code issues, ... features are in XS 6.x but the mono 'mcs' compiler has had C#6 features since their release